update vitepress to 1.3.4 disables all images in public folder
Edit: It turns out that using the image url (with '?url' appended to the image path) has suddenly stopped working in vitepress 1.4.3. So for now it's best to ignore the advice that appears in the console when referencing images from the public folder.
I have a vitepress project where I reference a lot of images from the public folder.
This is because the images are linked dynamically (in custom vue components).
In vitepress 1.3.1 this works well, when I update to 1.3.4, the images are not displayed.
During startup a lot of warnings (1 per image) are displayed in the console like these:

Assets in public directory cannot be imported from JavaScript.
If you intend to import that asset, put the file in the src directory, and use /src/img/0004IMG_10938_copy.jpg instead of /public/img/0004IMG_10938_copy.jpg.
If you intend to use the URL of that asset, use /img/0004IMG_10938_copy.jpg?url.

FWIW, I already do use the ?url syntax.
An example of how images are referenced in code:
I use a custom Vue component for some pages, in the template I have:
<img
  v-if="hasImg"
  :src="doc_image"
  :class="getClass()"
  alt=""
  @click="fsView = true"
/>

In the script section:
const getImg = computed((): string => {
  return withBase(`/img/${frontmatter.value.image}?url`)
})

In the onBeforeUpdate hook:
doc_image.value = getImg.value

Regardless, it used to work in 1.3.1 and suddenly stopped working in 1.3.4, which is weird.
I used this approach after the vitepress docs, see: https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets#the-public-directory

It would help to show exactly how the assets are being used in your code, but it sounds like you have import statements referencing the public directory.  As the error states, don't import from public (you don't need to).  If you are, remove the import lines of code.  You can just use the url, even if dynamic.

I updated my question with the requested info, but I still think it's weird that this suddenly stops working after an update.
